# Why does macOS intermittently drop packets over WiFi?

Tags: wifi

I have a 2020 13" M1 MacBook Pro. My WiFi is eero pro 6. Recently I observed that I have a small amount of packet loss ~0.1%. Although the packet loss is tiny, it is puzzling me. The weird part is that I only seem to be having packet loss on Apple computers over WiFi. I have an older Intel Macbook Pro which also experiences similar packet loss. I have a Mac Mini that also experiences packet loss over WiFi but it doesn't over ethernet. Here's the weird part. I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon running Linux which doesn't seem to be experiencing any packet loss over the same WiFi network.

None of the Macs experience packet loss at the same time. When I run ping, I see them experiencing packet drops at different times. I also have pings running in multiple terminal tabs to different destinations (e.g. google.com, WiFi Router, Internet Gateway) on each computer. Funny enough there is packet loss at different times to each destination. On my X1 Carbon, I don't see packet loss anywhere.

X1 Carbon is using 5GHz network as well as WiFi 6. It's not connecting to the 2.4GHz band. I checked this on Eero app and confirmed.

I initially suspected my broadband provider was having issues. However, I seem to be experiencing packet loss only on macOS machines and not a Linux machine. Packet loss also isn't limited to Internet destinations. It's occurring to Intranet destinations as well. I suspected rogue devices giving out EMF causing radio interference but then I would see packet drops across all devices simultaneously. That doesn't seem to be the case either.

The packets are also lost at different times in different terminal tabs on the same devices so I doubt it could be the WiFi. If there is a periodic WiFi glitch I would expect to see all ping destinations having issues at the same time. This is perplexing. The weirdest part is that I always had issues with WiFi on Linux and never on macOS.

I have tried the standard update & reboot, reconnect WiFi but nothing seems to eliminate the issue.

Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Interesting thoughts. I am a new Mac user and I am experiencing similar issues. My guess is that processor peaks or something running in background is affecting our network experience. But it is just a guess, since I am not experienced enough to troubleshoot what is happening in a MacOS computer...